# XPath following-sibling not working

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this:

```
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>
  <from>2</from>
  <heading>WHAT YOU WANT</heading>
  <body>No not this</body>
</details>
```

I'm trying to grab **WHAT YOU WANT** strictly by first finding a match of "1" in the summary, then finding "2" in the from, and lastly grabbing the node just after the one with "2". (Just take the conditions of requiring checking 1 and 2 for granted - this is a simplified example of a larger problem.)

I tried this but it only matches "Node from 2":

```
//details[summary[text()="1"]]//following-sibling::*[contains(text(), "2")]
```

Even though my understanding from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp tells me this should work?

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//details[1]/summary[.='1']
            /following-sibling::from[.='2']
            /following-sibling::heading
```

will select the `heading` element following the `from` element whose string value equals 2 following the `summary` element whose string value equals 1, all contained within the first `details` element in the document.

---

Responding to follow-up questions in the comments:

> From w3schools, the / indicates that we're looking for children of the
>   previous node, so a / after summary, to me, means that we're looking
>   at children of summary, for which there is nothing... Why?
>
> Oh I see - if you use an axis right after the /, the meaning is not
>   necessarily child anymore; it's whatever the axis specifies, like
>   following-sibling.

Right, your original confusion stemmed from the meaning of `/` in XPath.

`/` separates [***location steps***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Location-Steps).  A location step consists of an axis, a node test, and zero or more predicates.   The default axis is `child`, but others are possible.  In the above XPath, the `following-sibling` axis is used.

Comment: What if there is a gap between <summary> and <from> with an unknown # of other nodes? ...Actually, never mind this still works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - can you add a little explanation? From w3schools, the / indicates that we're looking for children of the previous node, so a / after summary, to me, means that we're looking at children of summary, for which there is nothing... Why?

Comment: Oh I see - if you use an axis right after the /, the meaning is not necessarily child anymore; it's whatever the axis specifies, like following-sibling.